# WebRequest GetResponse stuck with default proxy

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I have the following code

```
    private bool IsOnline()
    {
        try
        {
            var wr = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.google.com");
            wr.KeepAlive = false;
            wr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            using (wr.GetResponse())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When I execute it it remains stuck on GetResponse line forever.

Thanks to the responses we found that the problem is in the default proxy.
In fact if I construct a new proxy in the following way it works

```
        var registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", false);
        var proxy = (string)registry.GetValue("ProxyServer");
        var isProxyEnabled = (int)registry.GetValue("ProxyEnable");

        if (isProxyEnabled > 0)
        {
            wr.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, true, null, System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
        }
```

The problem is that this workaround code read from the registry the proxy that was manually set. It doesn't works if the user have choose "Automatically detect settings".

so:
- how can be found the proxy address in that case?
- why the default proxy does not work?

Comment: does it get stuck on first try or on n-th try?

Comment: If it works with Fiddler, it's likely a proxy issue... can you access google.com from IE ?

Comment: @DanielMošmondor at the first try

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Yes, I can access the google.com from IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in webproxy auto-detection.

By the way I found a more elegant workaround that allows me to use my initial code.
So after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191023/how-does-windows-actually-detect-lan-proxy-settings-when-using-automatic-confi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895754/dynamically-using-a-webproxy-with-wpad-script) questions I have put this code in the App.config file

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true" >
      <proxy autoDetect="True" scriptLocation="http://wpad/wpad.dat"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

This allows the program to skip the internet option settings and go staight to check the wpad (similarly as firefox does)